# I'm getting assertion error when using not.eql when running test from Postman collection

Tags: postman, postman-testcase, type-assertion

My main objective is to check VarA not suppose to match with VarB.
So I used assertion to check on this.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json()
varA= jsonData.body.SubA
varB= jsonData.body.SubB
pm.expect (varA) .to.not.eql (varB)
```

It works fine with .to.eql, but not the case with not equal
I saw from this site [https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/] it is not recommended. Any alternative I can use?
Thank you

Comment: What is the value of the data you're checking? Saying that you want to check that A is equal to B could be anything.

Comment: its a GUID that i extract from response body

Comment: Is it just a GUID? Is it in a nested array or object? Are there more properties? The question doesn't tell anyone anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the variables before using expect and in the the expect, you can check the result of their comparison.

```
var flag = true;
if (varA != varB) 
flag = false;

pm.expect(flag).to.equal(false);
```